# Where is a private instance variable of an abstract class created in the heap?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, abstract

```
abstract class A {
    private int a;
    public A(int x) {
        a = x;
    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B(int x) {
        super(x);
    }
}

class TestB {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b = new B(5);
        System.out.println(b.getA());
    }
}
```

In this situation when i say `B b=new B(5);` the super class constructor is called and the private instance variable is initialized to 5. So when i say `getA()` on `class B`'s object reffered by `b` it returns **5**. As the instance variable `a` of `class A` is private it will not be inherited by the `class B` . So where does the instance variable `a` is created(on heap) . Had it been a `public` it would have been a part of `class B` instance on Heap. Also `class A` is an abstarct class so it can not be instantiated.

Comment: "As the instance variable a of class A is private it will not be inherited by the class B . " - plain wrong, of course it is inherited! It is just not accesible except `getA()` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is no difference where the instance variables are allocated no matter if they are private, public, from a super class, from a abstract super class

typically the sequence will be something like

1. reference to the `B.class` object
2. block of `Object` instance variables (including helper fields for GC, the monitor for synchronisation,...)
3. block of `A` instance variables (only `a` in this case)
4. block of `B` instance variables (none in this case)

however each implementation of a JVM is free to choose how it allocates each of them

and access control is enforced by both the compiler and the JVM

Comment: so when the object of class B is created on heap , it will have all the instance variable of Object class , Class A and class B .

Comment: @Pankaj yep, but again that is a common way to do it, there are other ways like allocating separate blocks and linking them like a linked list, but the other one is faster

Answer (score 3):

Instance of variable 'a' would be created on heap inside object of class 'B'. and, it would still be created inside object of class 'B' where instance 'a' being public.

**OBJECT** of a subclass must contain its superclass's private fields. Having no access to a private member doesn't mean its not there.

As the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.2) states.

> Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by
>   subclasses of that class. Only members of a class that are declared
>   protected or public are inherited by subclasses declared in a package
>   other than the one in which the class is declared.

The sub-class doesn't private fields of super class. OBJECTS of subclasses contain private fields of their superclasses. The subclass itself has NO NOTION of private fields of its superclass.

Answer (score 0):

All abstract does is say "you can't create this class on its own". Everything defined within the class works exactly the same as for a non-abstract class.

So in other words remove the "abstract" keyword above and the resulting compiled bytecode will look almost identical.

It changes how you can use the class, not the behavior of what the class contains.

Comment: Since we cannot create instances of an abstract class, where will the private field in the abstract class get it's memory? Is the abstract class assigned memory in the heap?

Comment: When you create a concrete class extending an abstract class then any members for the abstract class are created/assigned/allocated/etc as part of instantiating that concrete class, exactly the same as for any non-abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Rule of Inheritance!!!

From [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

> A subclass does not inherit the private members of its parent class. However, if the superclass has public or protected methods for accessing its private fields, these can also be used by the subclass.